# Probability of getting the third ace in the j'th draw

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

So the problem is the following:

Given a complete deck of 52 cards, 9 cards are drawn one by one with reposition.
What is the probability that in a hand (of 9 cards) in which 3 aces come out, the 3rd will come out at the j'th draw?

**My answer:**

I was able to reach the correct answer (according to the solutions to the exercise) for the 9'th draw, which is

$$\binom{8}{2}\left(\frac{4}{52}\right)^3\left(\frac{48}{52}\right)^6$$

My thinking being: Probability of getting 2 aces in the first 8 cards times the probability of getting an ace in the 9'th (and last) card.

For the j'th draw I ended up with the following answer:

$$\binom{j-1}{2}\left(\frac{4}{52}\right)^3\left(\frac{48}{52}\right)^6$$

The thinking being very similar to the one I used before. According to the solution this is wrong. The correct answer should be:

$$\binom{j-1}{2}\left(\frac{4}{52}\right)^3\left(\frac{48}{52}\right)^{j-3}$$

Where did I go wrong? Did they actually mean "at least 3 aces"?

Comment: You are finding probability of $3$ aces in $j$ draws and _not_ $9$ draws where $j \leq 9$. If you plug in $j = 9$, you get your first answer.

Comment: It does not matter what cards you get after $j$ draws. It could be any of the $52$ cards.

Comment: The question explicitly says that 9 cards are drawn (so 9 draws with j ≤ 9) . Still, I think you're right. Also the question after is about summing j to infinity, so I suppose that means j can be greater than 9. On the other hand I feel like the question is not well phrased if that's what we were supposed to to calculate.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is exactly 3 aces in the 9 cards you can calculate the number of different positions for the aces, i.e.

```
AAA------  // ace in position 1, 2, 3
AA-A-----  // ace in position 1, 2, 4
A-AA-----  // ace in position 1, 3, 4
-AAA-----  // ace in position 2, 3, 4
AA--A----  // ace in position 1, 2, 5
... etc ...
```

That is $$\binom{9}{3} = 84$$

combinations in total.

The last ace can be in position 3, 4, ... 9

If the last ace is in position 3 there need to be exactly 2 aces in the 2 positions before position 3. Now calculate in how many ways that can be done:

$$\binom{2}{2} = 1$$

If the last ace is in position 4 there need to be exactly 2 aces in the 3 positions before position 4. Now calculate in how many ways that can be done:

$$\binom{3}{2} = 3$$

If the last ace is in position 5 there need to be exactly 2 aces in the 4 positions before position 5. Now calculate in how many ways that can be done:

$$\binom{4}{2} = 6$$

And so on...

This gives

```
Last ace in position 3 :  1 combination  --> probabilty  1/84
Last ace in position 4 :  3 combinations --> probabilty  3/84
Last ace in position 5 :  6 combinations --> probabilty  6/84
Last ace in position 6 : 10 combinations --> probabilty 10/84
Last ace in position 7 : 15 combinations --> probabilty 15/84
Last ace in position 8 : 21 combinations --> probabilty 21/84
Last ace in position 9 : 28 combinations --> probabilty 28/84
```

So in general

$$\binom{j - 1}{2} / 84$$

Comment: This was also one of my answers while attempting to solve the problem (I think this is the conditional probability for the j'th draw having the 3rd ace given that we have 3 aces in a hand of 9 cards). Apparently this was not what was asked for after I checked the answer. I think you confirm my initial suspicion that this question is not asked correctly.

Comment: @PedroCardoso hmm,,, the problem statement says "... **in a hand (of 9 cards) in which 3 aces come out** ..." so to me it's pretty clear that this is about  conditional probability. Anyway... what was the correct answer?

Comment: I mentioned it at the end of my question. Thanks for your answer anyway!